# Does Azure functions Fan-out / Fan-in func always have better performance than just running a single function thread?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm wondering if the new Fan-out and Fan-in func. in azure function is something to correlate with paralell.foreach vs single threaded foreach.

In some cases foreach is to perfer over paralell.foreach. If its a smaller task to be run the foreach is much faster.

Is it same the for Fan-out / Fan-in when using Azure functions? That just keep doing it with one function rather than scaling it out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, if your activity to be executed multiple times is something lightweight (e.g. adding numbers), it's going to be faster to execute it just within the single Function without remote calls, queues, and leaving the process whatsoever.

Fan-out / Fan-in pattern is only valid for expensive computations or IO operations that can benefit from parallelization.

If you have a specific use case in mind, you should add it to your question to make it less vague.

Comment: I don't have use case because this was just me being curious on how to approach the fan-out / in function. Or rather something to keep in mind when using azure functions. Nonetheless you gave me the answer I was more expecting but wanted to confirm it. so thanks.